# Trying to apply hover: to a Tailwind CSS custom-class I made, but it doesn't seems to work

Tags: css, next.js, hover, tailwind-css

Example:

```
.btn {bg-blue-500 text-2 text-orange-300}
.btn2 {bg-orange-500 text-2 text-blue-300}
```

### Attempted:

**Edit:** I'm sorry I forgot to include the code I was using... it was late night.

```
< button className="btn hover:btn2"/>   <---this does not work btn2 does not actually get applied as a hover
```

`btn` of course appears, but upon hovering, `btn2` styling does not appear.

If i'm doing something stupid or I clearly missed something already stated in the docs, feel free to just point me in the direction.

I've tried searching but I'm going in circles and I just have a lot of styles I'd like to change functionally by applying them in different states, but its going to be a pain in I have to create a separate `.btn .btn2 btn2-hover btn-hover` etc.. etc..

Is it a variant issue? Or is it a process that reads the `css` in a certain order? Could it be that I'm expecting hover to be applied to all internal `css` when it really doesn't do that? Or do I need to make some exception? I'm jumbled.

Comment: Why should anything happen on hovering? You don't have any `:hover` rules in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was in the docs. If anyone has this problem, it occurred because I had my declared styles under tailwind @components, when it should be tailwind @utilities.

```
@layer utilities{
.btn {bg-blue-500 text-2 text-orange-300}
.btn2 {bg-orange-500 text-2 text-blue-300}}
```

And then use the states as you would - for example, in this case

```
<button className="btn hover:btn2"/>
```

Above now will work!

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to apply **Pseudo-classes** like **:hover**:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

and if you're using css, you can use **@apply** in your style and then use tailwindcss class. In that case, you must also use **:hover**

Comment: when I do that I get an error that focus class does not exsist. 
**code**:

```css


.focus-ring {
  @apply focus:ring-2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's a setting problem check your index.css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html, body, #root{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}
```