# Why is the hover effect not working[Tailwind CSS]

Tags: html, css, hover, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

## HTML CODE

```
<div class="flex justify-center"><p class="font-bold text-[58px]">Title</p></div>
        <div class="grid grid-flow-row row-span-4 gap-[90px] mt-10">
            <div class="grid grid-flow-col col-span-2">
                <a href="#"><img class="h-[235px] w-[395px] bg-slate-50 rounded-[30px] relative left-[80px] border-2 border-black hover:rboxshad" src="./images/sz2.png" alt="img-sz"></a>
                <div class="h-[145px] w-[650px] rounded-[30px] relative top-[90px] right-[225px] bg-[#F0F0E1] border-2 border-black -z-20"></div>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
```

## CUSTOM CSS

```
.rboxshad{
    box-shadow: 8px 8px black;
}
```

Why can't i see the shadows for this image?

I'm trying to create a box containing an image with the neubrutalist aesthetic so that when the cursor is hovered over the image the shadow becomes visible, but the hover effect doesnt seem to work. the shadow is perfectly visible without using `hover:` so theres no problem with the `.rboxshad` class. what is possibly wrong here?

Comment: When you are using custom css, the tailwind specific "hover:" prefix does not work. You have to manually define custom css for the hover. `.rboxshad:hover { /* your style */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Custom Tailwind Utilities](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-modifiers-with-custom-css)

Keep class `hover:rboxshad`

https://play.tailwindcss.com/V6m0guIaPb?file=css

```css
@layer utilities {
  .rboxshad{
      box-shadow: 8px 8px black;
  }
}
```

2. Only use css `:hover`

Change class `hover:rboxshad` to `rboxshad`

https://play.tailwindcss.com/wzTndV9Lr2

```css
.rboxshad:hover {
  box-shadow: 8px 8px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your question you can find your answer here, good luck.
[Trying to apply hover: to a Tailwind CSS custom-class I made, but it doesn't seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588274/trying-to-apply-hover-to-a-tailwind-css-custom-class-i-made-but-it-doesnt-see)