# How to use the hover state on a imported custom class in Tailwind

Tags: next.js, hover, tailwind-css

I'm working on a `next.js` project, I organized my `css` code into multiple `stylesheet` files, and imported into the `global.css`.

I want the menu item to change its color when its parent gets hovered.

While The custom utility class would work only if I put it inside the `global.css`directly. If I import the class as `.css`, it won't do.

I checked the doc of tailwind [Using multiple of css files](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-multiple-css-files)
and followed the steps :

- install the `postcss-import` plugin,
- add `'postcss-import': {},` at the `postcss.config.ts`.
- put the `@import` at the first line as required at the doc [Build time imports](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports)

None of these helped.

Here is my code :
In the `global.css`:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
  @import "./assets/css/components/menu";
...
```

In the `menu.css`:

```
.active {
    @apply text-Primary
  }
```

```
        <ul>
         <li class="group">
          <Link href="/hello" class="group-hover:active">Menu Item</Link>
        </li>
       </ul>
```

The `active` class isn't token into account while the other custom classes works perfectly fine via `@import`.

I tried to import `active` class as `.css` under `tailwind utility` layer following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588274/trying-to-apply-hover-to-a-tailwind-css-custom-class-i-made-but-it-doesnt-see), it doesn't work,  either.

All directions or suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't get the problem. Today I opened the `vscode`, tape the same code blocks, and it just works.
I document the subjects this post covered for people who's interested:

- [Using multiple files in tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-multiple-css-files)
- [Using with your own classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-with-your-own-classes) with modifier (hover, focus, active...)

> All of Tailwind’s modifiers are available to use with your own custom classes **as long as you’ve defined them in one of Tailwind’s layers or added them using a plugin**.

So the custom class isn't necessarily inside the `utilities`layer, In my case, I should write something like this :

Menu.jsx

```
...
    <ul>
         <li class="group">
           <Link href="/hello" class="group-hover:active">Menu Item</Link>
        </li>
    </ul>
...
```

In `global.css`:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
     @import "./assets/css/components/menu";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

...
```

In the `menu.css`

```
@layer base{
.active {
    @apply text-Primary
  }
}
```

Yesterday, when I embedded `.active` class inside `@layer base{}`, tailwind threw me an error : `@layer base is used but no matching @tailwind base directive is present.` Today the error has gone with no reason.